# MoviePy WriteVideoFile not working in compiled .app

Tags: python, tkinter, ffmpeg, pyinstaller, moviepy

Expected Behavior
When running moviepy from my script through the console the movie file writes correctly and without error. What should happen from the code below is the file writes a movie to the directory path I have selected.

Actual Behavior

When compiling the app with pyinstaller --noconsole, the app crashes when attempting to write the video file. Since this only occurs when in the no console app I wrote in a logger to catch the stdout. When opening the file it looks like the issue is occurring when trying to write the audio back into the video. Here is the output:

```
Moviepy - Building video /temp.mp4.
MoviePy - Writing audio in tempTEMP_MPY_wvf_snd.mp4
```

I added an error log file since posting this and the error message I receive is:

```
chunk:   0%|          | 0/111 [00:00<?, ?it/s, now=None]Exception ignored in: <function FFMPEG_AudioWriter.__del__ at 0x11538e340>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "moviepy/audio/io/ffmpeg_audiowriter.py", line 132, in __del__
  File "moviepy/audio/io/ffmpeg_audiowriter.py", line 121, in close
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Steps to Reproduce the Problem
The error only occurs in the no console mode after compiling the app. The code below works with the console open.

```
    def save_clip(self):
        clip = self.clip
        if float(self.convert_to_seconds(self.end_time.get())) > clip.duration:
            self.end_time.set(clip.duration)
        if float(self.convert_to_seconds(self.start_time.get())) < 0:
            self.start_time.set("0:00")

        clip = clip.subclip(self.convert_to_seconds(self.start_time.get()),self.convert_to_seconds(self.end_time.get()))
        return clip


    def save_video(self):
        clip = self.save_clip()
        directory = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(filetypes=(("MP4", "*.mp4"),("All Files", "*.*")), defaultextension='.mp4', initialdir=f'{os.path.expanduser}/Downloads', title="Video Clip", initialfile="clip")
        if not directory:
            self.progress_bar_stop()
            return
        try:
            path = self.downloads + '/logger.txt'
            sys.stdout = open(path, 'w')
            #shutil.move(f'{self.directory}/{self.video}', directory)
            clip.write_videofile(f'{directory}', audio_codec='aac')
            self.progress_bar_stop()
            messagebox.showinfo(title="Success!", message=f'Clip Saved: {directory}')
        except:
            messagebox.showerror(message='Your clip was unable to be made. Please reupload your video and try again.')
```

Specifications
Python Version: 3.12
MoviePy Version: 1.0.3
Platform Name: MAC OS
Platform Version: 12.7.1

TLDR: After compiling the app with pyinstaller I can click the save video button and select a directory. After selecting the directory the app crashes.

The output in my log file is:

```
Moviepy - Building video /temp.mp4.
MoviePy - Writing audio in tempTEMP_MPY_wvf_snd.mp4
```

**** UPDATE ****
I've compiled and tested the code on my windows PC and it works without issue. It seems to be isolated to MacOS.